# Validacion de rut en java

Tags: java

Este es el ejercicio: Cree un Programa que permita ingresar el Rut de una persona y muestre:

Si el Rut es válido o no, en caso que no sea válido permita ingresarlo nuevamente solo tiene 3 posibilidades de equivocarse, después de las 3 veces se termina el programa mostrando un mensaje de bloqueo, en caso que sea válido muestre mensaje.

Ingrese el Rut sin el verificador y el programa debe calcular y mostrar el verificador correspondiente.
El programa debe permitir el ingreso de tantos Rut como sea necesario.

Y asi lo hice yo:

(Esta es la clase):

```
    public class ValidacionRut {
        private int rut;
        private String rutDigito;
        private int Digito;
        private int Multiplo;
        private int Acumulador;

    public ValidacionRut(String rutDigito, int Digito, int Multiplo, int Acumulador, int rut) {
        this.rutDigito = rutDigito;
        this.Digito = Digito;
        this.Multiplo = Multiplo;
        this.Acumulador = Acumulador;
    }

    public ValidacionRut() {
    }

    public String getRutDigito() {
        return rutDigito;
    }

    public void setRutDigito(String rutDigito) {
        this.rutDigito = rutDigito;
    }

    public int getDigito() {
        return Digito;
    }

    public void setDigito(int Digito) {
        this.Digito = Digito;
    }

    public int getMultiplo() {
        return Multiplo;
    }

    public void setMultiplo(int Multiplo) {
        this.Multiplo = Multiplo;
    }

    public int getAcumulador() {
        return Acumulador;
    }

    public void setAcumulador(int Acumulador) {
        this.Acumulador = Acumulador;
    }
    public int getRut() {
        return rut;
    }
    
    public void setRut(int rut){
        this.rut=rut;
    }
    public void ValidarRut(){
        int contador;
        contador=2;
        Acumulador=0;
        while (rut!=0){
            Multiplo=(rut%10)*contador;
            Acumulador=Acumulador+Multiplo;
            rut=rut/10;
            contador=contador++;
            if(contador==8){
                contador=2;
            }
        }
      
    }
    
}
```

(Este es el main):

```
    public class Ejercicio_RUT {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
           ValidacionRut Leer=new ValidacionRut();
           
           int rut;
           String rutDigito = null;
           int Digito = 0;
           int Multiplo;
           int Acumulador;
           rut=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingresar el RUT de la persona"));
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El rut ingresado es: "+rut);
           ValidacionRut rutPersona= new ValidacionRut();
            rutPersona.ValidarRut();
          
           if(Digito==10){
               rutDigito="K";
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El rut es valido");
           }
           if(Digito==11){
               rutDigito="0";
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El rut es valido");
           }
           if(Digito>10 && Digito>11){
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Rut totalmente invalido");
           }
           
        }
        
    }
```

Pero no me toma del primer if hacia abajo, no se en que estaré fallando :(

Comment: Qué es exactamente lo que tienes que hacer? ya que creas elementos y nunca los modificas o usas, como sabes si un rut es valido o no?

Comment: El dígito verificador es lo que tengo que calcular principalmente, el enunciado lo deje arriba también al principio de la publicación, soy nuevo en este mundo de la programación por eso igual no tengo mucho conocimiento porque estoy recién partiendo.

Comment: Pero como verificas o cuando un rut es válido y cuando no? en qué momento obtienes ese resultado?

Comment: Eso es lo que tampoco se :( por eso pedi ayuda no se en linea estare fallando

Comment: ¿Qué es un RUT?

Answer (score 3):

Para validar el RUT puedes utilizar el siguiente método.

```
public static boolean validarRut(String rut) {

    boolean validacion = false;
    try {
        rut =  rut.toUpperCase();
        rut = rut.replace(".", "");
        rut = rut.replace("-", "");
        int rutAux = Integer.parseInt(rut.substring(0, rut.length() - 1));

        char dv = rut.charAt(rut.length() - 1);

        int m = 0, s = 1;
        for (; rutAux != 0; rutAux /= 10) {
            s = (s + rutAux % 10 * (9 - m++ % 6)) % 11;
        }
        if (dv == (char) (s != 0 ? s + 47 : 75)) {
            validacion = true;
        }

    } catch (java.lang.NumberFormatException e) {
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return validacion;
}
```

Comment: Te recomiendo leer el artículo [Te he votado negativamente porque es solamente código.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2882/)

Answer (score 1):

Algunas consideraciones adicionales, Validar los input que no sean Nulos.

```
private boolean isValidRut(String rut)
{
    boolean ret = false;
    if(rut != null && rut.trim().length() > 0)
    {
        try {
            rut = rut.replaceAll("[.]", "").replaceAll("-", "").trim().toUpperCase();
            char dv = rut.charAt(rut.length() - 1);
            String mantisa = rut.substring(0, rut.length() - 1);
            if( isInteger( mantisa ) )
            {
                int mantisaInt = Integer.parseInt( mantisa );
                ret = validarRut( mantisaInt, dv ) ;
            }
        }
        catch (Throwable e) 
        {
            error("[isValidRut] ["+rut+"]", e);
        }
    }
    return ret;
}

private boolean validarRut(int rut, char dv)
{
    int m = 0, s = 1;
    for (; rut != 0; rut /= 10)
    {
        s = (s + rut % 10 * (9 - m++ % 6)) % 11;

    }
    return Character.toUpperCase(dv) == (char) (s != 0 ? s + 47 : 75) ;
}

public boolean isInteger(String cad)
{
    for(int i = 0; i<cad.length(); i++){
        if( !Character.isDigit(cad.charAt(i)) )
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Estás cerca de la solución, tu algoritmo para calcular el dígito verificador es correcto.

Espero que este ejemplo aclare tus dudas y puedas implementarlo en tu programa.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // prueba de rut con dígito equivocado:
        int rut = 30686957;

        Boolean valido;
        int verificador;

        verificador = 1;
        valido = validarRut(rut, verificador);
        System.out.printf("El dígito verificador %d para el rut %d es: %s\n", verificador, rut, valido ? "válido" : "inválido");

        // prueba de rut con dígito correcto:
        verificador = 4;
        valido = validarRut(rut, verificador);
        System.out.printf("El dígito verificador %d para el rut %d es: %s\n", verificador, rut, valido ? "válido" : "inválido");
    }

    public static Boolean validarRut(final int rutSinVerificador, final int digitoVerificador) {
        int rut = rutSinVerificador; //rut sin dígito verificador.
        int contador = 2;
        int acumulador = 0;
        while (rut != 0) {
            int multiplo = (rut % 10) * contador;
            acumulador = acumulador + multiplo;
            rut = rut / 10;
            contador++;
            if (contador == 8) {
                contador = 2;
            }
        }
        int digitoCorrecto = acumulador % 10;
//        System.out.printf("El dígito verificador es: %d\n", digitoCorrecto);
        return digitoCorrecto == digitoVerificador;
    }
}
```

Comment: Te recomiendo leer el artículo [Te he votado negativamente porque es solamente código.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2882/)

Answer (score 0):

```
public String fc_DigitoValido(int paramRutInt)
{
    int vRut = paramRutInt;
    String vDigitoOK = "";
    int vAcumulador = 0;
    int vContador = 2;
    //
    while (vRut != 0)
    {
        int vMultiplo = (vRut % 10) * vContador;
        //
        vAcumulador = vAcumulador + vMultiplo;
        vRut = Math.round(vRut / 10);
        vContador++;
        if (vContador == 8) vContador = 2;
        //
    }
    int vResiduo = 11 - (vAcumulador % 11);
    //
    if (vResiduo < 10) vDigitoOK = String.valueOf(vResiduo);
    if (vResiduo == 10) vDigitoOK = "K";
    if (vResiduo == 11) vDigitoOK = "0";
    //
    return vDigitoOK.toUpperCase();
}
```